# Scala test a Map is bijective

Tags: scala, scala-collections, bijection

What is a simple approach to testing whether a `Map[A,B]` is bijective, namely for

```
val m1 = Map( 1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
val m2 = Map( 1 -> "a", 2 -> "a")
```

we have that `m1` is bijective unlike `m2`.

Comment: This is essentially a math question about the definition of bijection (possible HW help?). I for one got here because I was looking for a Bijective Map, which does not appear to be available in the standard scala library. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do

```
val m = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "a")
val isBijective = m.values.toSet.size == m.size
```

A bijection is one-to-one and onto. The mapping defined by a `Map` is  definitely onto. Every value has a corresponding key.

The only way it's not one-to-one is if two keys map to the same value. But that means that we'll have fewer values than keys.

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) -

For a pairing between X and Y (where Y need not be different from X) to be a bijection, four properties must hold:

1) each element of X must be paired with at least one element of Y 
    This is inherent nature of Map. In some cases it can be mapped to None which is again one of the element of Y. 

2) no element of X may be paired with more than one element of Y,
    Again inherent neture of Map.
3) each element of Y must be paired with at least one element of X, and
    Every element in Y will have some association with X otherwise it won't exist.
4) no element of Y may be paired with more than one element of X.
    Map doesnt have this constraint. So we need to check for this. If Y contains duplicates then it is violated.

So, sufficient check should be "No duplicates in Y")

```
val a = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Option[Int]]()
a(10) = None
a(20) = None
if(a.values.toArray.distinct.size != a.values.size) println("No") else println("Yes") // No

val a = Map("a"->10, "b"->20)
if(a.values.toArray.distinct.size != a.values.size) println("No") else println("Yes") // Yes

val a = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Option[Int]]()
a(10) = Some(100)
a(20) = None
a(30) = Some(300)
if(a.values.toArray.distinct.size != a.values.size) println("No") else println("Yes") // Yes
```